# Design Patterns for Game Objects in Game Loop

Tags: java

I am building out a Game application with game loop.  So I will have game objects with update/draw operations.  I was wondering if composition or inheritance is best approach or other design patterns to apply here?  Also I am wondering if I should make full scale game objects out of the areas in whch the game objects function?  If for example I have a game object like person or car and it is inside say a region like yard, should the yard itself be modeled as a game object also? another example would be if I had a boxing game, obviosly I would make the fighers game objects and the ring might be a canvas, but should the ring be a full scale object too?  Sensing fighters hitting the ropes for example?  And if so how would update/render interface differ.  How would one express figher inside/outside region/ring?  Or is it just not a good idea to make a game object out of an area?  I was hoping to hear from someone who has modeled this type of thing before.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as there are 100 different ways you could design a game "correctly."  You also seem to ask how to handle collision detection and position updates, which are *completely* separate questions from the design.  My advice - just start coding a game, and when you get stuck on something specific, come back and we can help you out.  Until then:  read and code, read and code...

Comment: No Daniel.  I don't want to get knee deep into the code and then decide this. I am going to look up front at the best way to model the game elements.  And so what I am looking to find out is what is the criteria for making something a first class game object vs. a region?

Comment: And Daniel you have 1 rep so you can't close it.

Comment: Developing a game should be fun, so just go and make it run first, refactor it later :)

Comment: Its runs Denis, but your answer does too!

Answer (score 3):

This question is probably better suited for GameDev.StackExchange.com. In any case, composition seems to be the more maintainable option. [Evolve your Hierarchy](http://cowboyprogramming.com/2007/01/05/evolve-your-heirachy/) is a commonly referenced article in this regard. As for regions/areas, those are merely objects used for collision detection, by what you're describing.

The arena object has a rendering component and a collision detection component. You do not need a "region" object, per-se, you simply instantiate an object with your own customized components. All your rope hitting/ring entering/ring leaving logic is based on the arena and fighter's collision components having been detected as colliding, that collision being dispatched to the two objects, and the two objects responding to that collision.

Answer (score 0):

My opinion:
try to define simple game object that will have all the main properties like draw(), update().. for example if you want to make a simple collision game where all objects are circles you should add functions like checkCollision(GameObject other), and double x, y, r. now you can easily inherit from this class and make ball, person, monster... and refer to them as game object and not each one separate. if you want make something more complicated like different collision areas then its the same idea of gameObject class which will have Area and checkCollision(GameObject other) and again you inherit from this and define their own areas but refer all of then as game objects.
there many open sourced java game competitions you can google and check how they did the game and learn from this.
Good Luck.